# Using an if-else statement in big-query with a IFNULL statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a delicate dilemma with follwing SQL statement in Bigquery:

```
ROUND(SUM(r.DeliveredQuantity * IFNULL(a.DirectCost,a.PurchasePrice))) AS TotalCost,
```

I need to change it to check if some articles are present or not and if they are, I have to do one expressiona and if not another expression.This is my check

```
IF(a.ArticleNumber NOT IN ("204","204.2","204.3","204.4","204.5","204.6","204.7")
```

If those articles are not present then I have to run following query:

```
ROUND(SUM(r.DeliveredQuantity * IFNULL(a.DirectCost,a.PurchasePrice)))
```

Otherwise ( and here is where the unfortunate part comes in I guess ) I have to run something like this:

```
ROUND(SUM(r.DeliveredQuantity * IFNULL(a.DirectCost,a.PurchasePrice) / (a.SalesPrice * i.CurrencyRate)))
```

So the whole code snippet I have so far is:

```
IF(a.ArticleNumber NOT IN ("204","204.2","204.3","204.4","204.5","204.6","204.7"),
   ROUND(SUM(r.DeliveredQuantity * IFNULL(a.DirectCost,a.PurchasePrice))),
   ROUND(SUM(r.DeliveredQuantity * IFNULL(a.DirectCost,a.PurchasePrice) / (a.SalesPrice * i.CurrencyRate)))
  ) AS TG,
```

The result is a error saying:

```
division by zero: 0 / 0
```

The IFNULL I have to run unfortunately since my users have not be consistent in their data input. But even when only using one of either choices inside the IFNULL, I get the same response saying division by zero: 0/0

Endresult is that IF certaina rticles are present, then I need to get those including the i.CurrencyRate, otherwise without i.CurrencyRate. Any ideas?

PS! I followed this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#if)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF(a.ArticleNumber NOT IN ("204","204.2","204.3","204.4","204.5","204.6","204.7"),
   ROUND(SUM(r.DeliveredQuantity * IFNULL(a.DirectCost,a.PurchasePrice))),
   ROUND(SUM(SAFE_DIVIDE((r.DeliveredQuantity * IFNULL(a.DirectCost,a.PurchasePrice)) , (a.SalesPrice * i.CurrencyRate))))
  ) AS TG,
```